# Stencil test alternative

Tags: c++, opengl

I write a plugin for host application which draws some geometry using OpenGL 2.0

I need to perform basically a stencil test, but for some reason host application has stencil buffer disabled (GL_STENCIL_BITS == 0). As such I am looking for alternative solution (or maybe a way to enable stencil buffer).

The procedure requires a two step approach.

First all items are drawn in multi-pass manner. All of them need to be drawn in depth buffer, however parts will need to be removed later (after all items were drawn). I can mark these unwanted parts with color, alpha or stencil (though as noted it doesn't work in this case).
Later all I need to do is set depth value to 1.f for every pixel in buffer which has some color or alpha value. The last part would be simple with stencil buffer, but as noted it's not available.

Alpha test seems to work only on values that are to be drawn rather than ones that are already drawn. Or am I missing something?

I tried also copying buffer to CPU memory (glReadPixels), modify it and return (glDrawPixels), but for some reason it's working only with simple scenes. With more complex scenes it fails in glReadPixels, also performance is really poor.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is? I was going to suggest using an alpha test in lieu of the stencil buffer, but the end of your question already mentions that.

Comment: Yes, it would really help if you could elaborate on your use case. Particularly the "wipe some areas of depth buffer" part is unclear to me. How do you determine which areas of the depth buffer should be wiped?

Comment: Thank you for comments. I've updated question post. Hopefully it's more clear now. Thank you.